# python for loop to evaluate equation

Tags: python

I'm asked to write a function that should return the sum of the following series `1000 + 1/1**2 + 1/2**2 + 1/3**2 + 1/4**2 + ... + 1/n**2`
for the given integer n.
For example, for n = 0, the function should return 1000, for n = 1,
the function should return 1001, for n = 2, the function should return 1001.25, for n = 3, the function should return 1001.3611111111111, etc.

I know for sure this needs to be done by for loops and range functions.
Here's my code

```
if n<0:
        return None
if n>0 or n==0:
        for i in range(1,n-1):
            result=1000+1/(i**2)
            return result
```

But it keeps return None when n=o,1,2,3
I'm not sure how to fix this code...

Answer (score 2):

In each iteration, you are not updating `result` using the previous value of it. (Also you are returning `result` prematurely.) Update the variable by using `result = result + 1 / (i ** 2)`, or equivalently, `result += 1 / (i ** 2)`.

```py
def foo(n):
    result = 1000
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result += 1 / (i ** 2)
    return result

print(foo(0), foo(1), foo(2), foo(3)) # 1000 1001.0 1001.25 1001.3611111111111
```

Or, using (generator) comprehension,

```py
def foo(n):
    return 1000 + sum(1 / (i ** 2) for i in range(1, n + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any if statements. What you're doing right now is calculating `result`, then immediately returning the result on step 1.

```py
result = 1000
for i in range(1,n+1):
    result += 1/(i**2)
return result
```

Comment if anything doesn't make sense

Comment: Ok got it. It's like whatever n is we need to have 1000 first. yeah it makes sense.Thank you very much^^

Answer (score 0):

First, you can only return from within a function, but your code has no function definition included - maybe you forgot. Second, if this code is part of a function, the first iteration of the loop will throw you out of the function as soon as it hits return, so this function, if implemented, will not complete the intended loop iterations. Since this is a homework question, I will not complete the code, but I hope this gives you a start.

Comment: Yessss I understood the error now^^Thank you very much!